# Python ImageMagick pip install of pymagick not working

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, imagemagick, pip

I'm looking to install image magic with pip. I was under the impression that pymagick was the way to do this.

I would like to use it to determine color schemes of images.

pip install ... ImageMagic,python-pythonmagick, pythonmagick all have the cannot find error. Ex:

> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ImageMagick

pymagick on the other hand is found. However I get the following error:

> pip install pgmagick Downloading/unpacking pgmagick   Downloading
>   pgmagick-0.5.7.tar.gz   Running setup.py
>   (path:/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py)
>   egg_info for package pgmagick
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 17, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py",
>   line 74, in 
>           raise Exception("Magick++ not found")
>       Exception: Magick++ not found
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 17, in
>
> File
>   "/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py",
>   line 74, in
>
> ```
> raise Exception("Magick++ not found")
> ```
>
> Exception: Magick++ not found
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick
>   Storing debug log for failure in /Users/tai/.pip/pip.log

Here is Pip's Log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Tue Jul  8 13:18:54 2014
Downloading/unpacking pgmagick
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/
  URLs to search for versions for pgmagick:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.0.1.tar.gz#md5=ec9d56805757910bfc456f39f4ceda3b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.0.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.0.2.tar.gz#md5=165dd9d97f8eb472e712952815b7e390 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.0.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.0.3.tar.gz#md5=032b3c729ba420c178eb96daf1d8b1e5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.0.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.0.4.tar.gz#md5=ab1d775514fe1bc67ca54723691056ac (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.0.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.1.0.tar.gz#md5=2ef55d503f3a3a1a9cdb50fb80464c97 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.1.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.1.1.tar.gz#md5=476883ca6cbc18b8914065d101b3f266 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.1.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.1.2.tar.gz#md5=bc0d668684a7504acbbc08f60cc5dc9c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.1.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.0.tar.gz#md5=2cd1ceb5d7778c0e2bf04209fc811766 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.1.tar.gz#md5=725caea88ba3399d952ddf147521e779 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.2.tar.gz#md5=7c6fc0151314d6f889e680b0bd517eaa (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.3.tar.gz#md5=36f7c4ba916dd013fcf216c5c9d65147 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.4.tar.gz#md5=4ba643ec357639a42bc4ee407733a152 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.2.5.tar.gz#md5=b917aa2c6122384786b428bd43d798e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.2.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.0.tar.gz#md5=618f180173c70765d77361a1cedbccfd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=964c4e0196e9a96b7e8e7bdde136ed65 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.2.tar.gz#md5=6ae060c4ab467083ca95556e64c70408 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.3.tar.gz#md5=b3b56050ce5119bb7ed96231ec061064 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.4.tar.gz#md5=9b6fe86de441aa4707bcfdc1362956e4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.5.tar.gz#md5=b61b4a2db08e9c7cff54abf581baed5f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.3.6.tar.gz#md5=a26e1ed354ba5bb2adef4a8d4920adbd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.3.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.4.1.tar.gz#md5=dc1d19565a94f53971bb69bac4d46247 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.4.2.tar.gz#md5=aec27a3df2387b4341ab002b6f45f13e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.4.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.4.tar.gz#md5=0cd7db596167830e950230b7a033c479 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.1.tar.gz#md5=c58f03556682268f277b5a71c6e83c92 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.2.tar.gz#md5=6e11c561e74b662605459c0c702ea4dc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.3.tar.gz#md5=4c324f1b82e39282e62831bc2865c774 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.4.tar.gz#md5=c10a454331ac1c359b39e50663fd28e4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.5.tar.gz#md5=d4e1d083de80938d570300b89af10f30 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.6.tar.gz#md5=01c5376f646c6ffa03eaea06d19e3650 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.7.tar.gz#md5=cb030312d72296c0feea29034613a2ff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.tar.gz#md5=2f4d7e6833fddae32ac4656fa56c2bca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/), version: 0.5
  Using version 0.5.7 (newest of versions: 0.5.7, 0.5.6, 0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4, 0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.5, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1)
  Downloading pgmagick-0.5.7.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.7.tar.gz#md5=cb030312d72296c0feea29034613a2ff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/)
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py) egg_info for package pgmagick
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise Exception("Magick++ not found")
    Exception: Magick++ not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick/setup.py", line 74, in <module>

    raise Exception("Magick++ not found")

Exception: Magick++ not found

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w5/w7rmb9zj7sz3wv8pq64c8h3h0000gn/T/pip_build_tai/pgmagick
```

I would like to use a imagemagick library locally (aka in python). What installation should I use instead?

Answer (score 9):

ImageMagick isn't a Python package - you install it separately (and before installing your Python dependencies)

See http://www.imagemagick.org/

Comment: how is using pip to attempt to install imagemagick not installing it seperately?

Comment: The Python packages you've tried don't try to install ImageMagick. Some Python packages do install other binaries, but these aren't installing the one key binary you need. It looks like they all have pretty bad documentation, so it's not a surprise this wasn't clear. You need to install ImageMagick - yourself - first.